# (Firebase Firestore)TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add another field value in a document but firebase returns TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function. Here's the code:

```
async function linkLCSN(cor, sn) {
  try {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "cor", cor), {
      sn: sn,
    }, {merge: true});
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

I've already succeeded in doing this way but I don't know why this time it keeps giving me this error. This is the working code:

```
async function submitToDatabase(name, email, cor, cs, cn, concern) {
    try {
        //Set Datas 
        await setDoc(doc(db, "cor", cor), {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        cor: cor,
        courseSection: cs,
        contactNumber: cn,
        isViewed: false,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        }, {merge: true});
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cor", cor, "concerns"), {
        concernData: concern,
        });
        console.log("Yung betlog nasa:" + docRef.id);
        //Do page changes
        let a = document.querySelector(".concern-main-container");
        let b = document.querySelector(".concern-preview-container");
        a.style.display = "none";
        b.style.display = "block";
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
        //Custom Alert
    }
}
```

Comment: This typically means you're calling a writing function with some illegal values. Can you edit your question to: 1) show how `db` is initialized, 2) log the value of `cor` and show the updated code and its output, 3) the complete stack trace of the error message you get?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've found out the cause and it was the cor that was giving an invalid value.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem Sandren Troy!  --- This type of troubleshooting is always best to do before you post the question here, as it's actually quite common for developers to find the problem on their own when doing so. For this and similar advice, I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I was experiencing this same "TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function" error with Firestore v9, and I came across this question while trying to figure it out. Sharing some feedback for others that find this in the future: I love Firestore and Firebase, but sometimes it is difficult to figure out exactly what an error message is telling you. In this case, "TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function" means you have an invalid doc reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem by checking every type of params that passing to `doc()`, that params should not be `Integer`. It must be `String`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using v9 of firebase (modular version). It may sound silly, but make sure that you have initialized your app and that you are using a valid reference to a collection.

For example:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {/** your firebase config properties **/};

const app = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Then to add a new document, you can do:

```
const createDocument = (collectionName, document) => {
    const colRef = collection(db, collectionName);
    return addDoc(colRef, document);
};
```

Remember the *addDoc* function returns a promise, so be sure to handle this is the caller of *createDocument*